# How to change nuxt.js router to use custom path?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

For a software development marketing site, I have more than 30 landing pages which I like to keep them in `./pages/landing` folder. So, obviously the files inside `./pages/landing` can be accessed by, for eg:

```
www.lorem.com/landing/python-development-experts/
www.lorem.com/landing/java-development-experts/
```

but I need to eliminate `/landing/` from the path and still like to keep the files inside `./pages/landing` folder, but need access the files using this paths:

```
www.lorem.com/python-development-experts/
www.lorem.com/java-development-experts/
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did in `nuxt.config.js`

```
router: {
  extendRoutes: (routesIn) => {
    routesIn.forEach((r) => {
      if (r.path.includes('/landing/')) {
        r.path = r.path.replace('/landing', '');
      }
    });
    return routesIn;
  },
},
```

Comment: And it looks like this might be a good solution. I tried to play around with routes this morning and nothing else seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

you can extend your route checkout this link

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/112

Maybe its help !
Thanks !